# Is it possible to open an existing contact card by using JavaScript APIs for Office in a Outlook Add-In?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin

I have no clue on how to do it so that's the reason I am not giving more information.

In case it's not possible to do by using JavaScript APIs for Office, is there any other way?

[Open Contact Card Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4r3b.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot open contact card with Office.js API. What you able to do is use [Contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.contact?view=outlook-js-preview) simple type to build your own view of the contact information available through the object.
You may write COM/VSTO add-in for Outlook Desktop on Windows. In this case you would get full access to any property of the contact.